# How to put linebreaks in asp.net resource files

Tags: asp.net, resources

I've a label in an asp.net page that gets its text from a global resource file somthing like this:

```
<asp:Label  ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:MyResource, MyString %>" />
```

The resource string for MyString contains text with a linebreak like:

line1

line2

When the label is rendered I get the following html

```
<span id="Label1">line1line2</span>
```

but instead I want it to be rendered as

```
<span id="Label1">line1<br/>line2</span>
```

Is there a standard way making this happen without putting br-Tags in the resource file or manually replacing text in the resource string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources are just plain text, you'll have to post-process them after pulling the data from the resource file to change newlines to `<br/>`'s.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way is to put `<br />` tags in the text.

Comment: as I said I don't want to put br-Tags in the resource strings